# How can I solve error with TensorFlow 2.0?

Tags: tensorflow

I am new to Tensorflow and am using Keras to help me. I have this code:

```
import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow import keras
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

dataset = keras.datasets.fashion_mnist

(train_images, train_labels), (test_images, test_labels) = dataset.load_data()
```

However, when I run this I get this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/[REDACTED]", line 8, in <module>
    (train_images, train_labels), (test_images, test_labels) = dataset.load_data()
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow_core/python/keras/datasets/fashion_mnist.py", line 59, in load_data
    imgpath.read(), np.uint8, offset=16).reshape(len(y_train), 28, 28)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/gzip.py", line 276, in read
    return self._buffer.read(size)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/gzip.py", line 482, in read
    raise EOFError("Compressed file ended before the "
EOFError: Compressed file ended before the end-of-stream marker was reached
```

I visited all the files quoted but couldn't find a problem

using iMac, Python 3.6

Help!

Comment: You might have run this and saved a corrupted version (due to interrupted connection) of the data. Try finding the files Keras stored and deleting them and rerunning the script.

Comment: @thushv89, Thanks! I'll check that and get back to you ASAP

Comment: @thushv89 Where can I find the files keras stored? The TF package is so confusing :-)